# NullPointerException on AJAX when I pass a value, but it is acceptable when I send nothing

Tags: java, ajax

I get this error when I input a value in the field:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
ServletBiblio.obtenerDatos(ServletBiblio.java:26)
ServletBiblio.doGet(ServletBiblio.java:178)
```

Here are the mentioned lines:

```
if(clave.isEmpty() || titulo.equals("") || autor.equals("") || editorial.equals("") || existencia.equals("") || imagen.equals(""))

//datos = obtenerDatos(request);
String cve = request.getParameter("clave");
datos = libroad.consultarClaveJsp(cve);
```

Im really desperate and have tried everything, any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Adding more Servlet code. Here is where the if condition is:

```
private String obtenerDatos(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    String datos;

    clave  = request.getParameter("clave");
    titulo = request.getParameter("titulo");
    autor  = request.getParameter("autor");
    editorial = request.getParameter("editorial");
    existencia = request.getParameter("existencia");

    if(clave.isEmpty() || titulo.equals("") || autor.equals("") || editorial.equals("") || existencia.equals(""))
        datos = "VACIO";
    else
    {
        try
        {
            int n = Integer.parseInt(existencia);
            datos = clave+"_"+titulo+"_"+autor+"_"+editorial+"_"+n+"_"+"imagen.jpg";
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
        {
            datos = "NO_NUMERICO";
        }
    }

    return datos;
}
```

And the method where I need to use `clave` is here:

```
if(request.getParameter("bConsultarClave") != null)
    {               
        //datos = obtenerDatos(request);
        String cve = request.getParameter("clave");
        datos = libroad.consultarClaveJsp(cve);

        if(datos.equals("ERROR_CONSULTAR_CLAVE"))
        {
            //taDatos.setText("Error en Consulta por Clave...");
            respuesta = "Error en Consulta por Clave...";
            response.sendRedirect("RespuestaServer.jsp?datos="+respuesta);
        }
        else
        {
            if(datos.equals("NO_CLAVE"))
            {
                //taDatos.setText("No se localizo la clave "+cve);
                respuesta = "No se localizo la clave "+clave;
                response.sendRedirect("RespuestaServer.jsp?datos="+respuesta);
            }
            else
            {
                //editar(datos);
                //respuesta = procesarDatos1(datos);
                respuesta = datos;

                response.sendRedirect("RespuestaServer3.jsp?datos="+respuesta);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Clave/cve/clave is null?

Comment: What is null? the variable `clave` or request parameter `clave` or `cve`? the if condition for `clave` before request get parameter does nothing.. We might need more of your servlet/controller code.  And this does not look like a javascript question

Comment: @Sachin Updated the question.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz I dont get why it is null.

Comment: @Rud0lph Where do you get the null pointer exception ?

Comment: @Sachin It does not tell me in which line, only lists the following: `java.lang.NullPointerException
 ServletBiblio.obtenerDatos(ServletBiblio.java:26)
 ServletBiblio.doGet(ServletBiblio.java:178)`

Comment: Whats in at line 26 in `ServletBiblio.java` ?

Comment: `request.getParameter( ... );` can return NULL. Checking for "isEmpty" on a `null` object will result in an NullPointerException. Are you sure all parameters are set? Probably you cannot be sure, so test them for null before using them to test for is Empty... `if(clave == null || clave.isEmpty() || ...`